# xamppp. Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Myswl Log file

```
2021-05-18 11:38:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-05-18 11:38:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-05-18 11:38:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-05-18 11:38:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-05-18 11:38:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-05-18 11:38:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-05-18 11:38:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-05-18 11:38:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-05-18 11:38:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-05-18 11:38:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-05-18 11:38:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-05-18 11:38:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-05-18 11:38:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.17 started; log sequence number 47187; transaction id 8
2021-05-18 11:38:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-05-18 11:38:31 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-05-18 11:38:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210518 11:38:31
2021-05-18 11:38:31 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```